# Deleting all items from cosmos DB in batch: 404 not found

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have following code:

```
CosmosClientOptions options = new CosmosClientOptions() { AllowBulkExecution = true };
CosmosClient cosmosclient = new CosmosClient(connStr, options);
Container container = cosmosclient.GetContainer("CoachAPI", "Vessels");

await VesselsContainer.DeleteItemAsync<CoachVessel>("81c91c3a4f4841529bf36badfbb4a2ba", new PartitionKey("name"));   
or
await VesselsContainer.DeleteItemAsync<CoachVessel>("81c91c3a4f4841529bf36badfbb4a2ba", new PartitionKey("XXXa Soya"));
```

When running code I get:

> code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0;
> ActivityId: ; Reason: ();'

Any pointers how to fix this?

> Partion key: /name

This is my document:
[image]

Comment: Exactly which operation is throwing?

Comment: await Task.WhenAll(concurrentDeleteTasks.Take(3));

Comment: The real problem with the code is in this sentence: `container.DeleteItemAsync<string>(item, new PartitionKey("id"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has been tested in person and you can copy it directly to your project and run it.

*The format of item is shown in the figure.*

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System.Linq;

namespace CosmosGettingStartedTutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        // <Main>
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Beginning operations...\n");
                CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("https://localhost:8081/", "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");
                Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("Items");
                Container container = database.GetContainer("test");
                // Query for an item
                FeedIterator <response> feedIterator =  container.GetItemQueryIterator<response>("SELECT * FROM c");

                List<Task> concurrentDeleteTasks = new List<Task>();

                while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    FeedResponse<response> res = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                    foreach (var item in res)
                    {
                        concurrentDeleteTasks.Add(container.DeleteItemAsync<response>(item.id, new PartitionKey(item.adress)));
                    }
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(concurrentDeleteTasks.Take(3));
            }
            catch (CosmosException de)
            {
                Exception baseException = de.GetBaseException();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} error occurred: {1}", de.StatusCode, de);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End of demo, press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        public class response
        { 
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string adress { get; set; }
            public string _rid { get; set; }
            public string _self { get; set; }
            public string _etag { get; set; }
            public string _attachments { get; set; }
            public long _ts { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is my problem you cannot use id as partion key? e do exactly the same?

Comment: I have updated my post with more data. I will try to move away from using id and see if that works.

Comment: I tried adding name as partition key but same. I have simplified my original post.

Comment: OK got it working. First error was that partion key is not name but value of the partion key. Thanks appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you use the correct container.
In your case

```
Container container = cosmosclient.GetContainer("CoachAPI", "Vessels");    
await container.DeleteItemAsync<CoachVessel>("81c91c3a4f4841529bf36badfbb4a2ba", new PartitionKey("XXXa Soya"));
```

instead of

```
Container container = cosmosclient.GetContainer("CoachAPI", "Vessels");
await VesselsContainer.DeleteItemAsync<CoachVessel>("81c91c3a4f4841529bf36badfbb4a2ba", new PartitionKey("XXXa Soya"));
```